# JavaScript check whether iterator includes value

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator

For a JavaScript array, the `includes(value)` function returns true, if and only if the array contains the value.
What is a good and performant equivalent to check, whether a value is included in an [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) (e.g. `map.values()`)?

First approach (maybe not the most performant one):

```js
Array.from(it).includes(value)
```

Second approach (not that short):

```js
const iteratorIncludes = (it, value) => {
  for (x of it) {
    if (x === value) return true
  }
  return false
}
iteratorIncludes(it, value)
```

Comment: `map.has()` [Map.prototype.has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has)

Comment: @pilchard, this checks only the key of a map.

Comment: That second one looks good. Sure, you need to stow away the helper function somewhere, but the call is short and efficient. Alternatively, use the [proposed iterator helpers](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers) and check `it.some(v => v === value)`.

Comment: @Bergi can you make an answer?

Comment: @qwr done, see below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second approach looks good. Sure, you need to stow away the helper function somewhere, but you need to declare it only once so it doesn't matter - the call is short and efficient (even shorter than your first approach).

Alternatively, use the [proposed *iterator helpers*](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers) and check `it.some(v => v === value)`<sup>1</sup>. They don't offer an `includes` method that mirrors the `Array` API yet.

<sub>1: Technically, `includes` uses the [*SameValueZero* comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#same-value-zero_equality), which has a different result than `===` for a `value` of `NaN`.</sub>